# Не меняется ориентация экрана при повороте экрана

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Для xml layout создал lanscape вариант ориентации.
Но при повороте экрана не меняется ориентация. В манифесте нет никаких ограничений на ориентацию экрана.  Подскажите в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Забыл добавить, используется библиотека moxy для реализации mvp паттерна.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема устранена, надо было удалить setRequestedOrientation